# Joi validation to allow empty spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, joi

I would like my Joi middleware to keep the alphanum() validation but also allow empty spaces in both `event_name` and `venue_name`.
I've checked several questions on Stack and the Joi docs without being able to get the correct answer. Here's what I have:

```
const Joi = require('joi');

module.exports.eventSchema = Joi.object({
    event: Joi.object({
        event_name: Joi.string().alphanum().max(50).required(),
        venue_name: Joi.string().alphanum().max(50).required(),
    }).pattern(/^\s*\w+(?:[^\w,]+\w+)*[^,\w]*$/, Joi.string())
});
```

Right now, the input below works just fine:

```
test
```

However, this input error's out:

```
test test
```

How do I allow for spaces in my form validation?

Comment: Maybe you want `/^\s*\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\s*$/`?

Comment: Ah, you mean the whole input can be just spaces? Then use `/^\s*(?:\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\s*)?$/`

Comment: Sorry @Wiktor Stribiżew should have clarified more in my question above (added now). Right now the text input `test test` error's out. However, `test` by itself works fine. I'd like the former to work as well.

Comment: I think the problem is not with the regex, but with `.alphanum()`. It seems to require only letters and digits in the string and does not allow spaces. Try to remove these.